# Setting locale in a linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github-actions

To overcome an [error](https://github.com/docker-android-sdk/android-30/issues/10) in Github actions pipeline I'm trying to set locale in my Ubuntu machine. Given below is how I do it from my pipeline.

```
- name: SetLocale
      run: |
         sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tzdata locales -y && sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
         sudo localectl set-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
         export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
         sudo update-locale
         locale -a
         locale
         locale -c -k LC_NUMERIC
         localectl status
```

With the above code, I am getting the error shown below.

```
    Run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tzdata locales -y && sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy InRelease [4563 B]
Get:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease [23.8 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease [48.9 kB]
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli jammy InRelease [3575 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease [3611 B]
Get:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease [23.8 kB]
Get:10 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy/main amd64 Packages [776 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:12 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy InRelease [12.9 kB]
Get:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [2960 B]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [927 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [36.3 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [449 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [569 kB]
Get:19 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages [21.7 kB]
Get:13 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease [8993 B]
Get:20 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli jammy/main all Packages [1096 B]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Get:23 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli jammy/main amd64 Packages [786 B]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
Get:25 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main arm64 Packages [14.3 kB]
Get:26 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main amd64 Packages [66.0 kB]
Get:27 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main armhf Packages [7354 B]
Get:28 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy/main all Packages [904 B]
Get:29 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [4684 B]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [42.2 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1174 kB]
Get:33 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy/main amd64 Packages [106 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [450 kB]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [851 kB]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [27.0 kB]
Get:37 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 Packages [66.4 kB]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [49.4 kB]
Fetched 25.3 MB in 2s (10.5 MB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
locales is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1).
The following packages will be upgraded:
  tzdata
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
Need to get 349 kB of archives.
After this operation, 88.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 tzdata all 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [349 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 349 kB in 0s (3724 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 84513 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) over (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up tzdata (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...

Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
Local time is now:      Tue Jun  6 16:03:04 UTC 2023.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Jun  6 16:03:04 UTC 2023.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Could someone please guide the cause of this issue and how it can be overcome? Any help is much appreciated.

**System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.**

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate

Comment: IIRC, after setting the locale, relogin/restart is required. Otherwise, it won't take affect. What is your use case? Why do you need it?

Comment: I have provided a link in my question which points to the exact same issue I have - ie; OS and file system combination not supporting unicode file names properly. It is happening in a cloud virtual machine where my build is running.

Comment: Can you not configure this VM directly via SSH instead of doing it from your GHA workflow?

Comment: Please share the related parts of that `run` property: `uses` etc.. Better is if you provide an [mre] to show  your issue.